# dart 3 alpha: switch with pattern matching doesn't compile

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

I am trying to compile a simple example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  debugPrint(printShape(Circle()));
}

sealed class Shape {
}

class Square implements Shape {
}

class Circle implements Shape {
}

String printShape(Shape shape) => switch (shape) {
  Square() => 'square',
  Circle() => 'circle'
};
```

with option `--enable-experiment=sealed-class,variance,value-class,extension-types,macros,inference-update-2,records,inline-class,class-modifiers`, however, I get an error:

```
ERROR: lib/main.dart:15:35: Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'switch'.
main.dart:15
ERROR: Try inserting an identifier before 'switch'.
ERROR: String printShape(Shape shape) => switch (shape) {
ERROR:                                   ^^^^^^
ERROR: lib/main.dart:15:35: Error: 'switch' can't be used as an identifier because it's a keyword.
...
```

I use Flutter version 3.8.0-14.0.pre.2 on channel master / Dart version 3.0.0 (build 3.0.0-257.0.dev)

What am I doing wrong? Or is this not yet implemented in Dart 3 alpha?

Comment: add `patterns` to enabled experiments

Comment: @pskink Thank you so much! I seem to have checked several times, but it turns out I missed the most important thing. Thank you!

Comment: sure, your welcome, btw do you know any good site with dart 3 pattern introduction / tutorial? I know only patterns proposal on dart's github

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/blob/master/accepted/future-releases/0546-patterns/feature-specification.md

Comment: @YeasinSheikh yes this one is the only one i have found

Comment: I don't know, just following this and [Language funnel](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/projects/1)after simon showed on QA humday.

Comment: @pskink Unfortunately, only 0546-patterns/feature-specification.md that Yeasin Sheikh said earlier. Just to try it out, I started with a simple example.

Comment: @pskink Try https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhYTFglbF2k